# What do I return from a method that returns just Task and not Task<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

What do I return from `D4()`?

```
async static Task D4()
{
    Console.Write("Enter the divisor: ");
    var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine((24 / n).ToString());

    // NONE OF THESE WORK
    // THE COMPILER COMPLAINS WITH AN ERROR THAT SAYS:
    // Since 'Program.D4()' is an async method that returns 'Task', 
    // a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression.
    // Did you intend to return 'Task<T>'?
    // return new TaskCompletionSource<object>().Task;
    // return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    // return Task.FromResult<bool>(false);
    // return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

I asked [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31874517/303685) earlier and it probably worked in my situation then but I have no recollection of the situation now. Also, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13127177/303685) seems to suggest the same thing that I am trying. I am not sure why it doesn't work in my case.

**UPDATE**

For the sake of completeness, here is the whole of the relevant bit of code.

```
async static Task A4() { await B4(); }
async static Task B4() { await C4(); }
async static Task C4() { await D4(); }
async static Task D4()
{
    Console.Write("Enter the divisor: ");
    var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine((24 / n).ToString());

    // return new TaskCompletionSource<object>().Task;
    // return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    // return Task.FromResult<bool>(false);
    // return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Comment: nothing... this should work...

Comment: You don't return anything.  Treat it as if it was a `void` method.

Comment: Before worrying about making it async at all, first decide what this method *does*.  Which is what?  In an entirely non-async world, does this method return anything?

Comment: @David You are right. I would in a real project. I am just trying to throw an exception from `D4()` to see if its context is preserved at the top of the call-stack in the `Main` method. `Main` calls `A` calls `B` calls `C` calls `D` -- each awaiting the other except there are no awaits in the `Main` because that's the entry point.

Comment: Does your version of .NET support `Task.CompletedTask;` ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman No, that's v4.6. I am targeting v4.5.2.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: So... If this method wouldn't otherwise return anything in a non-async world, why is it trying to return something in an async world?  An `async Task` method just needs to internally await something.

Comment: @David: It doesn't actually *have* to await anything... but you'll get a warning if it doesn't.

Comment: I am confused, I know I can return `void` but the documentation recommends that we return `Task` instead so the caller can query for the completion or cancellation or the occurance of exceptions in the task, which is why I have the signature returning a `Task` instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary What the anwer in that link says is also what I was saying. I wasn't asking the question about when to have the return type be a `Task` as against `void`. I was, in fact, politely saying to the person who suggested that I make the return type `void` that what they were saying went against the grain. It wasn't a sound suggestion.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can think of `async` as constructing a `Task` wrapper *for* you. If you don't use `async`, then you can return an actual `Task` object.

Your first code example is using `async` but then you try to return a `Task`. Returning a `Task` isn't necessary with `async`:

```
async static Task D4()
{
  Console.Write("Enter the divisor: ");
  var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  Console.WriteLine((24 / n).ToString());

  return; // May be removed, since it is implicit.
}
```

Your second code example removed the `async` and then tries to not return anything; in this case, since `async` isn't creating a `Task` for you, you need to create one yourself:

```
static Task D4()
{
  Console.Write("Enter the divisor: ");
  var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  Console.WriteLine((24 / n).ToString());

  return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

The first example (where `async` creates the `Task` for you) is more idiomatic. Note that you should also be using an `await` in the `async` method.

Comment: Many thanks. I have been awake too long. *If you don't use async, then you can return an actual Task object.* That was that. I have really been awake too long.

Comment: Remember today there is `Task.CompletedTask`.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the async keyword so it becomes

```
static Task D4()
{
    return Task.FromResult(0); // or one of the others from your post
}
```

You don't need to await a `Task.FromResult()`. Even if you would use a Task that does actual work using `Task.Run()` as the last part of the method. See [Awaiting tasks: Return task or await if no code after await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061849/awaiting-tasks-return-task-or-await-if-no-code-after-await)

Comment: The latter part is incorrect. Basically, you should treat an `async Task` method as if it were a `void` method; plain `return;` statements are fine, but you can't return a value.

Comment: My bad, 2nd option shouldn't return anything indeed

Comment: There's no point in awaiting `Task.FromResult` though. As that's always a completed task, it'll reach the end of the method synchronously.

Comment: Exactly, technically it compiles and works but I gather the actual implementation will be different so I outlined both possibilities

Comment: I don't see why there's an "exactly" there - just remove the body of the second part entirely. You don't need to await anything.

Answer (score 1):

You don't return anything from a function with Task as the return type. Similar to what you would do with void.

You could however use "return;" again as you could do with void.

**Edit**

You should be able to return nothing if you include "async" in the function deceleration.

Example form [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UlW5a2)

Comment: `'Program.D4()': not all code paths return a value`

Comment: Not all the methods that return `Task`, only the ones that have the `async` keyword.

Comment: I stand corrected, you need to include async in the function deceleration

Answer (score 0):

Well, I returned `default(Task)` just to make it shut up. I am not sure what the purists will say about that. It seems to have worked and it is harmless I think?

```
static Task D4()
{
    Console.Write("Enter the divisor: ");
    var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine((24 / n).ToString());

    // return new TaskCompletionSource<object>().Task;
    // return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    // return Task.FromResult<bool>(false);
    // return Task.FromResult(0);

    return default(Task);
}
```

One criticism of this is that the caller will have no idea about what it has received and what its state is. This is an example and I don't really care but as a general principle, I think what I have illustrated should be avoided.

A slightly more safe but expensive approach might be to say this perhaps?

```
private static Task cachedNoOpTask = new Task(null);

...

return cachedNoOpTask;
```

Comment: This will return null which is probably not what callers will expect. Your question is about `async` methods while `D4` is not marked `async`. You should be able to use `Task.FromResult` to return a completed task since `Task<T>` extends `Task`. If you make `D4` async then you should not return a value.

Comment: @Lee Sorry, `D4` *was* marked `async` earlier but I posted the updated code in the interm of trying out various recommendations. I must have removed the `async` keyword during then. I have updated the code in the question.

Comment: Your updated async version of `D4` compiles, although you should get a warning about making it `async` since it doesn't `await` anything.