# Since 'func' is an async method that returns 'Task',a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return 'Task<T>'?

Tags: asp.net-core, return, task

Hello My Program got this error and i dont know why?

> Since 'InsertToHomeSecondPagesTableJob.Execute(IJobExecutionContext)' is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return 'Task'?

this is my code

```
   public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            var PagesScoreNewsHomePageTable = new PagesScoreNewsHomePageTable()
            {
             PagesID = 1,
             UserID = 22,
             Author = "jack"
            };                              
        _db.AddAsync(PagesScoreNewsHomePageTable);
        _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        
        return Task.CompletedTask;
 }
```

how can i solve this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do I return from a method that returns just Task and not Task<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646858/what-do-i-return-from-a-method-that-returns-just-task-and-not-taskt)

Comment: Do you intend to fire-and-forget the save changes call? Since currently it is not awaited.

Answer (score 1):

The simple and recommended way to solve this problem is using `await` keywords.

> The `async` and `await` keywords in C# are the heart of async programming.
> By using those two keywords, you can use resources in .NET Framework,
> .NET Core, or the Windows Runtime to create an asynchronous method
> almost as easily as you create a synchronous method.

You just need to change your code like:

```
public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            var PagesScoreNewsHomePageTable = new PagesScoreNewsHomePageTable()
            {
             PagesID = 1,
             UserID = 22,
             Author = "jack"
            };                              
       await _db.AddAsync(PagesScoreNewsHomePageTable);
       await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        
 }
```

More details about `async` you can refer to this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model).